# Error was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope

I have the following files and I don't understand why it doesn't work and why I obtain

> 'Pixel' was not declared in this scope

Here the header:

```
#ifndef TABRESULTATS_H
#define TABRESULTATS_H
#include "Ligne.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "Pixel.h"
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

class Tableresultats
{

    public:
        Tableresultats(vector<Pixel> pixels);
        Tableresultats(vector<Pixel> pixels, int seuil);
        Tableresultats();
        virtual ~Tableresultats();
    protected:
    private:
        vector<int> m_debut;
        vector<int> m_duree;
        vector<int> m_valeurMax;
        int m_seuilGris;
};

#endif // TABRESULTATS_H
```

The .cpp:

```
#include "Tableresultats.h"
#include "Ligne.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "Pixel.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int vmaxTemp;
int dureeTemp;

Tableresultats::Tableresultats();
{
    m_seuilGris=180;   //valeur par defaut
    vector<int> debut();
    vector<int> duree();
    vector<int> vmax();
    //ctor
}

Tableresultats::Tablesreultats(vector<Pixel> pixels);
{
    // ...
}

Tableresultats::Tableresultats(vector<Pixel> pixels, int seuil);
{
    m_seuilGris=seuil;   //valeur par defaut
    // ...
}

Tableresultats::~Tableresultats()
{
}
```

And my class pixel:

```
#ifndef PIXEL_H
#define PIXEL_H
#include <iostream>
#include "Tableresultats.h"
using namespace std;
class Pixel
{
    public:
   ...

    protected:
    private:
        int m_couleurRGB[3]; //La couleur du pixel
        int m_niveauGris; //Niveau gris
        int m_posX; //reference X
        int m_posY; //reference Y
};

#endif // PIXEL_H
```

I have other files but I don't understand why I have this problem:

> Pixel was not declared in this scope, line 16 Tableresultats.h header

if I have declared `#include <vector>` and `#include "Pixel.h"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between `Tableresultats.h` and `Pixel.h` (they include each other).

You'll have to resolve that by making proper use of forward declarations.

Or remove one of those includes if possible (from what you posted of `Pixel.h`, it doesn't look like it needs the include for `Tableresultats.h`).